# How to get second and third image url in string using php?

Tags: php

How to get second and third image url in string using php ?

My `$st_data` is

```
<img src="1.jpg"><img src="2.jpg"><img src="3.jpg">
```

Then i use this code

```
<?PHP
preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $st_data, $img_url);
echo $img_url[1];
echo $img_url[2];
echo $img_url[3];
?>
```

It's will echo only first image url, i want to know how can i get second and third image url with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` only matches the first instance. You need to use `preg_match_all`. Try this:

```
$st_data = '<img src="1.jpg"><img src="2.jpg"><img src="3.jpg">';
preg_match_all('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $st_data, $img_url);

echo $img_url[1][0];
echo $img_url[1][1];
echo $img_url[1][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't mandatory to use regular expressions:

```
$st_data = '<img src="1.jpg"><img src="2.jpg"><img src="3.jpg">';

$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($st_data);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$images = $domd->getElementsByTagName('img');

$second = $images[1]->getAttribute('src');
$third = $images[2]->getAttribute('src');
```